# Proof of the trace inequality in PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

From Evan's *Partial Differential Equations* in Ch. 5, there is what seems to be a relatively straightforward exercise (5.7) which is a proof of the trace inequality. Here is the statement of the problem:

> Assume that $U$ is bounded and there exists a smooth vector field $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\cdot \nu \ge 1$ along $\partial U$, where $\nu$ as usual denotes the outward unit normal. Assume $1\le p <\infty$. Apply the Gauss-Green Theorem to $\int_{\partial U}|u|^{p}\alpha\cdot \nu dS$, to derive a new proof of the trace inequality
> $$\int_{\partial U}|u|^{p} dS\leq C\int_{U}|Du|^{p}+|u|^{p}dx$$
> for all $u\in C^{1}(\bar{U})$.

I can handle the proof relatively easily up until the end. By assumption, since $\alpha\cdot \nu \geq 1$, we have

$$\int_{\partial U}|u|^{p}\alpha\cdot\nu dS \geq \int_{\partial U}|u|^{p}dS$$

Now applying the Gauss-Green Theorem to the left-side of this inequality we obtain

$$\int_{\partial U}|u|^{p}\alpha\cdot\nu dS=\int_{U}div(|u|^{p}\alpha)dx=\int_{U} div(\alpha)|u|^{p}+D|u|^{p}\cdot \alpha dx$$

I am not entirely sure what to do next with this, how does the smoothness of $\alpha$, for example, fit into this proof? Any suggestions on how to proceed would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first $1<p<\infty$ so that $|u|^p$ is in $C^1(\overline{U})$. Smoothness of $\alpha$ (which can be defined on all of $\Bbb{R}^n$) allows you to justify the use of the divergence theorem, and since $\alpha$ is a fixed smooth vector field, you have uniform bounds on it and all its first derivatives. So,
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial U}|u|^p\,dS&\leq\int_{\partial U}|u|^p\alpha\cdot\nu\,dS\\
&=\int_U[\text{div}(\alpha)|u|^p+p|u|^{p-1}\text{sgn}(u)Du\cdot \alpha]\,dV\\
&\leq C(\|\alpha\|_{\infty},\|D\alpha\|_{\infty})\int_U\left(|u|^p+p|u|^{p-1}|Du|\right)\,dV\\
&\leq C(\|\alpha\|_{\infty},\|D\alpha\|_{\infty})\int_{U}\left[|u|^p+p\left(\frac{p-1}{p}|u|^p+\frac{1}{p}|Du|^p\right)\right]\,dV\tag{$*$}\\
&\leq C(\|\alpha\|_{\infty},\|D\alpha\|_{\infty})\int_U\left(p|u|^p+|Du|^p\right)\,dV,
\end{align}
which completes the proof for $1<p<\infty$. If $p=1$, then you can work through the above derivation with the divergence theorem being applied in a weak sense, or you can (why?) simply take the limit $p\to 1^+$ above… this is why I kept the explicit lack of dependence of the constant $C$ on $p$ (why is this important?). Another way of arguing for $p=1$ is to apply the inequality above for $p=1$ with a ‘regularized’ function $u_{\epsilon}=\sqrt{|u|^2+\epsilon}$, and then taking the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$. There are several analysis tricks here for dealing with the edge case $p=1$, and you should gain familiarity with as many of them as you can.

For $(*)$, first recall Young’s inequality $ab\leq \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$, where $a,b\geq 0$ and $p,q\in (1,\infty)$ are Holder-conjugate exponents (so $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$). Now for any $\xi,\eta\in [0,\infty)$, apply this with $a=\eta$ and $b=\xi^{p-1}$ to get
\begin{align}
\xi^{p-1}\eta\leq \frac{\eta^p}{p}+\frac{(\xi^{p-1})^q}{q}=\frac{\eta^p}{p}+\frac{p-1}{p}\xi^p.
\end{align}

---

Note that if the Young’s inequality stuff is confusing, then to keep the gist of the argument in mind, focus on $p=2$, then the inequality simply says $ab\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ (which is equivalent to the obviously true inequality $(a-b)^2\geq 0$). This means in the above derivation, we simply use $2|u||Du|\leq |u|^2+|Du|^2$.

Having said that, Young’s inequality, and Holder’s inequality are basic inequalities fundamental for real analysis, and as such they should always come to mind as *suitable things to try* (even if it takes you a while to figure out the right constants/exponents).